# Verilog compilation error: unexpected '[', expecting "IDENTIFIER" or "TYPE_IDENTIFIER" or '#' or '('

Tags: verilog

I want to design a simple multiplier with the generate construct and two dimensional memory. But I can not compile the following verilog code. Could anyone give some hint please?

```
module classic_multiplier(
    a, b,
    a_by_b);
parameter M = 2;

input [M-1:0] a, b;
output reg [M-1:0] a_by_b [0:2*M-2];

//the first and
genvar i, k;
generate begin
    for(k = 0; k <= M-1; k=k+1) begin
        for(i = 0; i <= k; i=i+1) begin
            a_by_b[k][i] = a[i] & b[k-i];
        end
    end
end
endgenerate
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem here is that you have a 2D output port (`a_by_b`). I'm not quite sure why you would need it for a multiplier anyway, the output port size should be `2*M`, so:

```
output reg [(2*M-1):0] a_by_b;
```

Also, there is no need for the `begin` after `generate` (and thus no need either for the matching `end`), but ok, that's not really the problem here, you can add them if you want.

Next, for loops inside a `generate` block need to be named, for example:

```
generate
  for(k = 0; k <= M-1; k=k+1) begin : for_outer
    for(i = 0; i <= k; i=i+1) begin : for_inner
      a_by_b[k][i] = a[i] & b[k-i];
    end
  end
endgenerate
```

Of course, you will need to change the code inside the for loops if you change the definition of `a_by_b`.

Comment: Hi Darhuuk, I post what I really need to do in this new post. I think you will be more clear about what I need. Please share some insights. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964568/vhdl-convert-to-verilog

Answer (score 0):

When the tool sees `a_by_b[k][i] = a[i] & b[k-i];` it assures that a_bay_b is a module. Prefix an `assign` or `always  @*` to the line and the tool will accept accept the code.

A generate blocks expands the code during the compile elaboration time. With the given code:

```
genvar i, k;
generate
  for(k = 0; k <= M-1; k=k+1) begin
    for(i = 0; i <= k; i=i+1) begin
      a_by_b[k][i] = a[i] & b[k-i]; // Error will happen here
    end
  end
endgenerate
```

Will expand to:

```
a_by_b[0][0] = a[0] & b[0-0]; // * Compile Error *
a_by_b[1][0] = a[0] & b[1-0]; // **  Assignment without assign, always @*
a_by_b[1][1] = a[1] & b[1-1]; // ** block statement (e.g. always,initial)
```

The correct code with `assign`:

```
genvar i, k;
generate
  for(k = 0; k <= M-1; k=k+1) begin
    for(i = 0; i <= k; i=i+1) begin
      assign a_by_b[k][i] = a[i] & b[k-i];
    end
  end
endgenerate
```

Will evaluate to:

```
assign a_by_b[0][0] = a[0] & b[0-0];
assign a_by_b[1][0] = a[0] & b[1-0];
assign a_by_b[1][1] = a[1] & b[1-1];
```

Or with `always @*`:

```
genvar i, k;
generate
  for(k = 0; k <= M-1; k=k+1) begin
    for(i = 0; i <= k; i=i+1) begin
      always @*  a_by_b[k][i] = a[i] & b[k-i];
    end
  end
endgenerate
```

Will evaluate to:

```
always @*  a_by_b[0][0] = a[0] & b[0-0];
always @*  a_by_b[1][0] = a[0] & b[1-0];
always @*  a_by_b[1][1] = a[1] & b[1-1];
```

Alternatively an single always block can be used without a generate block:

```
integer i,k;
always @* begin
  for(k = 0; k <= M-1; k=k+1) begin
    for(i = 0; i <= k; i=i+1) begin
      a_by_b[k][i] = a[i] & b[k-i];
    end
end
```